# What is wrong with this C program?

Tags: c, pow

I just want to assign the value of *pow* to a variable, I've used this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main( void )
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
x=10;
y=2;

z = pow(x,y);
printf ("%d" , &z);

return 0;
}
```

but in output I get -1076813284 , I am sorry, but I just started learning C and in every tutorial everyone just print the value of pow, like

```
printf("Value 3.05 ^ 1.98 = %lf", pow(3.05, 1.98));
```

and I don't know how to assign it to a variable

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: Why do u print out `&z`?

Comment: thanks everyone we solved it, it was my noob mistake, I am new to this, in pascal I don't need &, i thought I need it here always, thanks all again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf ("%d" , &z);
```

prints the address of `z` (*), not its value. `printf("%d", z)` prints the value.

(*) Actually, the behavior is undefined and on a 64-bit CPU it will likely print half of the address.

Comment: thanks! in those beginner tutorials everyone uses & I thought it's obligatory

Comment: @Luka, For `scanf` maybe because C is pass-by-value, so `scanf` can't read into the variable otherwise.

Comment: You still need to change the printf to be a %f or %lf

Comment: The `z` is `int`. @Jack

Comment: @alk but pow isn't defined to return an int, just double. So unless you intend to have an implicit cast you need to change z to a double and %f in the printf.

Comment: @Jack; I am 100% agreed with you. That's what my answer says.

Answer (score 2):

`&z` is the address of the variable `z`. If you want to print out the *value* of `z`, then the code is simply

```
printf("%d", z);
```

You would use `&z` when *reading* a value into `z`, because `scanf` needs a pointer in order to modify your variable.

Answer (score 1):

`pow` returns `double` and it takes arguments of type `double`.

```
double pow(double x, double y)
```

You need `%f` specifier in `printf` and also remove `&` from `z`.

Another way is to cast the return value of `pow` to `int` and use `%d`

```
int z = (int)pow(x, y);
printf ("%d" , z);
```

Comment: Which `int` can convert to and from and still produce either 99 or 100.

Comment: @chris; What does that mean?

Comment: @alk; I know. Say this to chris :)

Comment: @alk; You can use either in `printf`.

Comment: I mean when the OP passes the `int` into `pow`, it gets converted to a `double`. When the OP stored the returned `double` into an `int`, it, too, gets converted back and thus `z` will be one of 99 or 100 due to floating-point inaccuracies. And since the OP's `z` is an `int`, `printf` needs to be told it's an `int` or the type of `z` needs to change (which is probably better in order to not maybe randomly print 99).

Comment: @chris; Converting `int` to `double` is fine but converting `double` to `int` is constraint violation.

Answer (score 1):

pow returns a double (and not a reference), you need to make your print statement:

```
printf ("%f" , z);
```

After changing z to a double:

```
double z;
```

Comment: `%f` is for `float`, not `double`.

Comment: @chris; Yes it is for `double` in `printf`. In case of `scanf` you need `%lf` for double.

Comment: @Jack, Oops, my bad. I was thinking of `scanf`. It wouldn't really make sense in `printf` considering it's passed in as a `double` anyway.